# How to show webp animation in Android

Tags: android, animation, gif, webp, fresco

I would like to use WebP format to animate GIFs as the alternative to native GIF format or MP4, but I have no clue how to actually decode it in Android and show it in the view.

The Giphy app could be used as the reference. I would like to achieve similar result with the webp animation.

I found a 3rd party library -  [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) (Facebook). It provides a view for the animation as well as animates it. But this library increases the build size by several(!) megabytes.

Does anybody have a solution or suggestion how to display the animated WebP animation on native Android (not in WebView)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The RedReader app has a custom implementation of a gif player, its open source so you can see it here https://github.com/QuantumBadger/RedReader/blob/master/src/main/java/jp/tomorrowkey/android/gifplayer/GifDecoder.java

Answer (score 1):

The "several" megabytes of Fresco become one megabyte if you ship separate APKs for different CPUs. See the [instructions](http://frescolib.org/docs/multiple-apks.html#_).